# Cannot find assembly for IObjectWithSite

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, .net-assembly, bho, ieaddon

I am trying to create a BHO and for that i need to implement IObjectWithSite. I have seen the msdn document at [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.ole.interop.iobjectwithsite%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), it mentions that the required assembly for it is Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop (in Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.dll). I have a fresh installation of Visual Studio 2010 sp1, but i cannot seem to find the dll anywhere on my disk and also when i try to add references from visual studio.

I have referenced the following assemblies as of now:

- MSHTML
- SHDocVw

But i am still not able to resolve the reference to IObjectWithSite.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to download the "Visual Studio 2010 SDK"

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=2680

Comment: That link won't work. It will give you a ridiculous errror saying Visual Studio 2010 is not found. The reason is if you have SP1 installed, you should install Visual Studio 2010 SP1 SDK instead. Use this link: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21835